# Exclude middleware from caching

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-cache

I have very simple middleware that track numbers of "hits" of an object.

```
class HitCount():
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'article_view':
            try:
                Article.objects.filter(slug=view_kwargs['slug']).update(hit_count=F('hit_count')+1)
            except:
                pass
```

The problem is, it doesn't work properly when ["per-site"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache) cache is enabled.

"hit_count" field (PositiveIntegerField) is updated only once per 5 minutes (cache timeout 300s), no matter how many times page was visited during that "5 minutes".
It doesnt have to be accurate, beacuse "hit_count" field isn't even displayed on front side. I need it only, to order articles via popularity. But "5 minutes measurement error" is too much.
How can I exclude that middleware from caching? Do I need to disable cache for whole view?

settings file, I tried to change middleware order, but no effect.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'blog.middleware.HitCount',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

view

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Article.objects.published()
    template_name = 'article.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FetchFromCache` middleware is fetching the page from the cache during `process_request`.

That means that the `process_view` middleware is never called.

You could try changing your middleware to override `process_request` instead. However, that might be tricky, because you won't have access to `request.resolver_match`.

Comment: Thank for answer, it works with process_request. I can get resolvers_match by importing resolvers (resolve(request.path)). Bad thing is, now every request is resolved two times :/ But I dont see big difference in performace. I will mark this as answered tomorrow. Maybe someone has other idea, till then